How to handle scheduler in schema-per-tenant multi-tenant spring boot application
I have implemented schema-per-tenant multi-tenancy in spring boot using AbstractRoutingDataSource, I can switch the schema depending on the request and perform db operation on the selected schema. My doubt is, in my application, I have schedulers and ScheduledExecutorService whose job is to delete some records in the db table periodically so, how the single scheduler will delete records in 'n' tenant tables?
What approach should I follow to handle this scenario in multi-tenancy,

Please provide code samples of your schedulers and datasources.
